# Unit Test CXF JAX-RS implementation without deploying to server

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, cxf, cxf-client

Working on a JAX-RS client using CXF.

**Requirement is to test the service side code from unit test case with the help of a test client without deploying the rest service to a server**

REST Service we implemented use HTTP headers to pass some information to the WS methods.

All the implementations I came across, so far,  have services deployed to a server.

Examples I tried to create a JAX-RS client

```
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS);
```

and

```
RestWSInterafce proxy = JAXRSClientFactory.create(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS, RestWSInterafce.class);
    Client client = WebClient.client(proxy);
    WebClient httpClient = WebClient.fromClient(client);
```

I tried configuring a CXF-Jetty implementation but didn't had any luck. Below is a snapshot from the Spring application context file

```
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http-jetty.xml" />

<jaxrs:client id="restWSClient" address="${server.address}" serviceClass="com.xyz.rs.RestWSInterface">
</jaxrs:client>
```

Is it possible to test without having the rest services deployed to a server?

---

### **Edit**

My main concern while posting this question is to test the method which expects HttpHeaders elements to be passed in the context. Consider the below GET method from my interface.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
@Path("/getMessage")
public Response getMessage(@Context HttpHeaders headers);
```

To Unit test this method, instead of calling the interface by deploying the application to the server, I wrote test case to call the implementation class directly and pass an implementor to HttpHeader as input. This solved my issue of unit testing the ws methods without deploying to the server.

```
public class HttpHeadersImpl implements HttpHeaders {

private MultivaluedMap<String, String> multivaluedMap;

public void setRequestHeaders(MultivaluedMap<String, String> multivaluedMap) {
    this.multivaluedMap = multivaluedMap;
}

@Override
public MultivaluedMap<String, String> getRequestHeaders() {
    return multivaluedMap;
}
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is it you want to test?

Comment: A REST Webservice with methods which consume and produce json content and a couple which produce multipart data.

Comment: The JAXRS resource is deployed into a container that at least needs to understand the http requests, such as servlet container, or grizzly, cxf can have other requirements. So the unit tests are usually written with starting embedded server as part of tests. You can look at cxf's [supported server list](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html) and choose which ever allows for being started embedded.

Comment: Do you want to test server functions or test that your client is working properly with a simulated server? In your code you are only considering the client side

Comment: Test the server side code from the test client in a simulated server.

Comment: I think you should distinguish between unit tests and integration tests. If you want to unit test your methods you can do this completely without a server. Just test the methods as you would any plain java method. If you want to do an integration test, you have to use a embedded server as @jan.supol suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch programmaticaly a CXF server from your unit tests without deploying into a server

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
sf.setResourceClasses(TestServiceImpl.class);
sf.setAddress("http://localhost:8080/testrs");
sf.create();
```

To start the endpoint you will need the `cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty dependency`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

The server could be the real or simulated only for testing. With the WebClient you can test the http transport.

If you work with CXF and Spring, you also can initialize the full context using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and inject the rest server to the unit test client. In this case you can test the services without http transport